# Converting JSON Result as an Array

Tags: objective-c

I have this JSON data :

```
array: {
    data = (
                {
            "com_id" = 1;
            "com_name" = Apple;
        },
                {
            "com_id" = 2;
            "com_name" = "Google";
        },
               {
            "com_id" = 3;
            "com_name" = "Yahoo";
        }
    );
    message = "Data found";
    response = success;
}
```

here's my code to fetch that data :

```
    NSURL * url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://jsonurlhere.com"];

    // Prepare the request object
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad
                                            timeoutInterval:30];

    // Prepare the variables for the JSON response
    NSData *urlData;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;

    // Make synchronous request
    urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                    returningResponse:&response
                                                error:&error];

    // Construct a Array around the Data from the response
    NSArray* object = [NSJSONSerialization
                       JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                       options:0
                       error:&error];

    NSLog(@"array: %@", object);
```

now, I want to use that JSON data into my PickerView. how to change that JSON data into array so that I can load it to replace my existing array (`self.nameCompany`)?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.nameCompany = @[@"Apple", @"Google", @"Yahoo"];
}
```

Comment: Look at your JSON data: That is not an array. It is a dictionary, and the value of the "data" key is an array ...

Comment: @MartinR : that's the point. I know that JSON is JSON, not an array. that's why I want to convert it into NSArray so that it can be used as a data in my UIPickerView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this code , your response is not a array but Dictionary.

```
-(void)loadData{

NSURL * url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://jsonurlhere.com"];

// Prepare the request object
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                            cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad
                                        timeoutInterval:30];

// Prepare the variables for the JSON response
NSData *urlData;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;

// Make synchronous request
urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                returningResponse:&response
                                            error:&error];

// Construct a Array around the Data from the response
NSDictionary* object = [NSJSONSerialization
                   JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                   options:0
                   error:&error];

NSLog(@"array: %@", [object objectForKey:@"data"]);


NSMutableArray *companyArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSDictionary *tempDict in [object objectForKey:@"data"]) {

    [companyArray addObject:[tempDict objectForKey:@"com_name"]];
}

self.nameCompany=[NSArray arrayWithArray:companyArray];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think It's helpful to you. Can you try this following link? It's not use to any supporting files. Also, see this link NSJSONSerialization supported URL
[NSJSONSerialization](http://sonnyparlin.com/2012/04/parsing-json-with-ios-5/)